# GCM push not received using amazon sns

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

I have strange issue regarding amazon sns. I am using nodejs sdk of amazon aws to send pushnotifications to android devices. The problem is when I send the message to amazon server it returns with a MessageID, but the message is not delivered.

Here's the code for amazon publish :

```
publishMessage : function(topicArn,message){
  var gcmMessage = JSON.stringify({data:message});
  var SnsMessage = JSON.stringify({default:"default",GCM:gcmMessage});
  var params = {
    Message : SnsMessage,
    TopicArn : topicArn,
    MessageStructure : "json"
  };
  console.log("AmazonService",params);
  return AmazonSns.publish(params).promise();}
```

If I publish using amazon console the notification is working perfectly.
Also I if i Remove JSON.stringify from gcmMessage it is sending pushnotification but without gcm data.

Answer (score 0):

I was making mistake using key in message of "from" and "to". I think gcm somehow already uses that key.